# How sort string with spaces in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, string-comparison

I need sort strings. But it doesn't sort correctly when it finds spaces in string. How can I make it not to sort spaces?

```js
const array = [
        { attributes: { name: 'abcd efg' } },
        { attributes: { name: 'Übd cd' } },
        { attributes: { name: 'Ku cdf' } },
        { attributes: { name: 'äb' } },
        { attributes: { name: 'abc' } }
      ]
      array.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.attributes.name.toUpperCase()
          .localeCompare(b.attributes.name.toUpperCase(), 'de', { sensitivity: 'base' })) { return -1 }
        if (b.attributes.name.toUpperCase()
          .localeCompare(b.attributes.name.toUpperCase(), 'de', { sensitivity: 'base' })) { return 1 }
        return 0
      })
console.log('typeof array', array)
```

I expect to see:

```
[
{ attributes: { name: 'abc' } },
{ attributes: { name: 'abcd efg' } },
{ attributes: { name: 'äb' } },
{ attributes: { name: 'Ku cdf' } },
{ attributes: { name: 'Übd cd' } }
]
```

Comment: What about removing the spaces before the conversion to uppercase? `name.replace(/\s+/g, '').toUpperCase()`?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it remove spaces but not affects on sort.

Comment: @SalmanA I edit my question to see.

Comment: Not sure why you're using result of `localeCompare` in `if`. It will be truthy for both 1 and -1. Also, your second `localeCompare`, it has `b.attributes` for both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `String.localeCompare` method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before, or after, or is the same as the given string in sort order... which is the same as what `Array.sort` is supposed to return:

```js
const array = [
  { attributes: { name: "abcd efg" } },
  { attributes: { name: "Übd cd" } },
  { attributes: { name: "Ku cdf" } },
  { attributes: { name: "ab" } }
];
array.sort((a, b) => a.attributes.name.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.attributes.name.toUpperCase(), "de", { sensitivity: "base" }));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: What does "de" mean?

Answer (score 2):

The way [`localCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) works is, if the first string is smaller i.e. comes before the second string, it will return a negative number.
And if the first string is greater i.e. it comes after the second string, it will return a positive number.

This line:

```
if (a.attributes.name.toUpperCase()
          .localeCompare(b.attributes.name.toUpperCase(), 'de', { sensitivity: 'base' })) { return -1 }
```

will be true even if the first string is greater or the second string is.

The problem is that `if (-1)` or `if(any_negative_value)` is considered `true`. Even if `localeCompare()` returns a negative value, your first `if` statement will always execute. The second `if` statement will never be executed. Therefore, no matter if the `a.attributes.name` is lexicographically greater or `b.attributes.name` is greater, the first `if` statement will always be executed.

You do not need the `if` statements. The `sort` function just needs the number returned by `localCompare()`.

Hence, you can simply return the value of `localeCompare()` and it will sort the attributes correctly.

```js
const array = [
        { attributes: { name: 'abcd efg' } },
        { attributes: { name: 'Übd cd' } },
        { attributes: { name: 'Ku cdf' } },
        { attributes: { name: 'ab' } }
]
      array.sort(
        (a, b) => a
          .attributes
          .name
          .toUpperCase()
          .localeCompare(b
            .attributes
            .name
            .toUpperCase(), 
            'de', 
            { sensitivity: 'base' }
          )
        );
console.log('typeof array', array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one....

```js
var hasLeading = s => /^\S+\s\S+\s\S+$/.test(s);
var array = [
    { attributes: { name: 'abcd efg' } },
    { attributes: { name: 'Übd cd' } },
    { attributes: { name: 'Ku cdf' } },
    { attributes: { name: 'ab' } }
];

array.sort((a, b) => hasLeading(b.attributes.name.toUpperCase()) - hasLeading(a.attributes.name.toUpperCase()) || a.attributes.name.toUpperCase() > b.attributes.name.toUpperCase() || -(a.attributes.name.toUpperCase() < b.attributes.name.toUpperCase())
);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove the spaces. Just using the lowercase version of the strings works.

```js
const array = [
  { attributes: { name: 'abcd efg' } },
  { attributes: { name: 'Übd cd' } },
  { attributes: { name: 'Ku cdf' } },
  { attributes: { name: 'ab' } }
];

const sensitivity = { sensitivity: 'base' };

function getLocale(a, b) {
  return a['localeCompare'](b, 'de', sensitivity);
}

array.sort((a, b) => {
  const al = a.attributes.name.toLowerCase();
  const bl = b.attributes.name.toLowerCase();
  return getLocale(al, bl) > getLocale(bl, al);
});

console.log('typeof array', array);
```